# Cantor-Schroeder for topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

So we know if $A$ and $B$ are sets and there is an injection from $A$ to $B$, but also an injection from $B$ to $A$ then there is a bijection between them. Does the analogous statements hold for topological spaces? I.e if $A$ and $B$ are topological spaces and there is an injective, continuous map from $A$ to $B$, but also one from $B$ to $A$, does it follow that the spaces are homeomorphic?

Comment: Consider the closed interval $[0, 1]$ and the open interval $(0, 1)$.

Comment: If both spaces are open subsets of an euclidian space we can say something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: @blamethelag Not much. In fact, for any two non-empty open sets $U,V\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, you can embed topologically either of them into the other.

Comment: @blamethelag However, invariance of domain comes into play if you want to prove that if $f:M\to N$ and $g:N\to M$ are, say, topological embeddings between compact connected manifolds (or compact with finitely many connected components) without boundary, then $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms themselves, which is a stronger instance of the conclusion of interest.

Answer (score 2):

No, the naive version (just injections) is easily shown to be false:

$[0,1)$ embeds into $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ embeds into $[0,1)$ (via $x \to \frac{x}{2}$, e.g.) while these spaces are not homeomorphic.

Even with two continuous *bijections* (so one from $A$ to $B$ and another one from $B$ to $A$) we cannot conclude to a homeomorphism between them; see the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/2060) for some examples of that.